# Java servlets, write data from text file to web page

Tags: java, servlets, ioexception

I have this servlet code in java:

```
package servlets;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.net.*;


public class Servlet1 extends GenericServlet{
 private ServletConfig sc;
 public void init(ServletConfig conf) throws ServletException{
     super.init(conf);
     sc = conf;
 }

 public void read_file(){
     String filename = "/web/WEB-INF/Data.txt";
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
     // Why this doesn't work ?

 }

 public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp) throws ServletException,IOException{   
     resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=windows-1251");
     PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
     pw.println("<html><head>");
     pw.println("<title>sdasdasda</title>");
     pw.println("</head><body><h2>Servlet information</h2>");
     pw.println("Servlet name - "+sc.getServletName()+ "<br>");
     pw.println("Servlet parametrs: <br>");
     //pw.println(read_file());
     Enumeration names = sc.getInitParameterNames();

     while(names.hasMoreElements()){
        String name = (String)names.nextElement();
        pw.print(name + ": ");
        pw.println(sc.getInitParameter(name)+"<br>");
     }
     pw.println("</body></html>");
     pw.flush();
     pw.close();
 }
 public void destroy(){
     sc = null;
 }

}
```

And this `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));` always shows that there is no suck file, but I put it in ProjectName/web/Web-INF/ folder. 
How do i read from this file, or get the right path to it 
?

Comment: try giving complete path: in your ide **right click on the file and go to Properties**; to get absolute path

Comment: As a side note, please do not use new FileReader() without explicitly specifying the encoding. You will save yourself and your colleagues a lot of grief down the road hunting encoding errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you are specifying an absolute path (your path starts with `/`)

Second FileReader is not the correct way of loading a resource in a web application, what is if your application war is not extracted? It will still fail.

You should use [ServletContext#getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to get an [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html?is-external=true) and use it to read your resource.

Comment: Still the same problem, i've put InputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Volodia\\IdeaProjects\\ProjectName\\web\\WEB-INF\\Data.txt");

Comment: @user3135093 Using `FileInputStream` has the same disadvantages as using `FileWriter`, both try to access the file by directly using the filesystem. Please make sure that the file `Data.txt` exists in the deployment and use `ServletContext#getResourceAsStream` so that the access happen through the `classpath`!